# Shopware6 : My order email is taking a long time to be sent

Tags: sendmail, mailer, shopware

I am facing a problem since I added the sendmail configuration in the .env file of my shopware folder.
[image]
See the above picture, If we click on "**Order with compulsory payment of the costs**", the page will start loading until the mail arrives in the inbox of the email address attached to the order. Which means that this page will load for like 5minutes.

Is there a way to shorter this time lapse OR to configure shopware so that he doesn't wait until the mail is sent?

Here is my mail config in .env file : ***MAILER_URL=sendmail://emakers.be***

Comment: Could you check the connection time for `emakers.be` or try to send an email from scratch and track the time for this to be sent?
Did you adjust the email template or methods that are used in this step?

Comment: I sent an email from scratch and it took like 1minute. 
I did not created the email template but what can I do to optimize this? also for the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this work by using an smtp office365 server.
Worked like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your sendmail in asynchronous way